# Passing non empty array of strings with null first indexes

Tags: c, arrays, access-violation

I need to pass an array of strings to function, I just want to fill the third item of the array, and keep all other items `NULL`, so I can fill it in the function that I passed the array to. But unfortunately it reads the passed array as `NULL` for all its items. and I can't figure out why that?

It reads `Msg` array as if it is all `NULL`, and doesn't read item 7 which it has already been set.

Here is my code:

```
void MSGCONT()
{
    char *Front= "0811";
    char *DateTime = "1701231335";
    char *Msg[130];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 130) {
        Msg[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    Msg[7] = &DateTime[0];

    Build(Msg, Front);
}

char *Build(char *Msg[130], char *Front) {
    Msg[0] = Front;

    while (Msg[1] == "") { // access violation reading location error.
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `Msg[i] = '\0';` --> `Msg[i] = "\0";`, `Msg` is an array of strings, not a string 2) Compare strings using `strcmp()` instead of `==`, `while(Msg[1] == "")` --> `while (strcmp(Msg[1], "") == 0)`

Comment: Either provide complete code or provide a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So many errors in such a small piece of code.

Comment: @KeineLust ok, but still it doesn't read Item 7, The "Msg" value when its been passed is '""'

Comment: @KeineLust: I am sure *you* know this, but still:  "*`Msg` is an array of strings*" well. well, no. `msg` is an array of pointers to `char*`. A `char*` in the 1st place points to `char` and doing so it *might* point to a C-string, yes.

Comment: @KeineLust well, yeah I'm dealing with C-strings in array, so if I'm doing it wrong please advice me how can I do it right?!

Comment: @KeineLust: `Msg[i] = "\0";` -> `Msg[i] = "";`.  The extra null byte is useless.

Comment: @chqrlie, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to decide whether you want to pass NULL or empty strings for array items not filled. I propose NULL for being less ambiguous, but you might choose empty strings for pragmatic reasons.
If you choose to use NULLs, you must check the pointers in your array before trying to access what they are pointing at.

Either way, you should pass the number of elements in the array as an argument to Build.

Let's look at a version with NULLs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES 130

char* Build(char* Msg[], int MsgCnt, char *Front);

void MSGCONT()
{
    char* Front= "0811";
    char* DateTime =  "1701231335";
    char* Msg[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES];
    int i =0;

    while( i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES)
    {
         Msg[i++] = NULL;
    }

    Msg[7] = DateTime;

    Build(Msg, NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES, Front);

}

char* Build(char* Msg[], int MsgCnt, char *Front)
{
   Msg[0] = Front;

   for (int i=1; i<MsgCnt; i++) 
   {
     if(Msg[i] != NULL)
     {
       printf("%ith item contains %s\n", i, Msg[i]);
     }
   }

   return "whatever";
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
   MSGCONT();
   return 0;
}
```

And here's at a version with empty strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES 130

char* Build(char* Msg[], int MsgCnt, char *Front);

void MSGCONT()
{
    char* Front= "0811";
    char* DateTime =  "1701231335";
    char* Msg[NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES];
    int i =0;

    while( i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES)
    {
         Msg[i++] = "";
    }

    Msg[7] = DateTime;

    Build(Msg, NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES, Front);

}

char* Build(char* Msg[], int MsgCnt, char *Front)
{
   Msg[0] = Front;

   for (int i=1; i<MsgCnt; i++) 
   {
     if(strcmp(Msg[i], "")!=0)
     {
       printf("%ith item contains %s\n", i, Msg[i]);
     }
   }

   return "whatever";
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
   MSGCONT();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, still it hasn't solve my problem, still the same old issue, which is 'Msg' has been passed fine from 'MSGCONT()' with all its Items, but when I receive it in 'Build' function as an Empty array with no Items.

Comment: I've extended the examples a bit, so you can copy and compile them directly. They work as expected. (The second example had a bug in the original answer)